FontAwesomeIcon not showing
I'm trying to add an icon to my react app that can conditionally be a plus or a minus. The icon is contained inside a circular button that works correctly aside from the fact that the icon it should contain is not shown.
Here is my code:

const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

const handleOpening = () => {
    setIsOpen((prev) => !prev)
}

<button onClick = {handleOpening} className = 'expandButton'>
    {!isOpen ? (
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-plus" />
    ) : (
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-minus" />
    )}
</button>

This is my package.json file and the dependencies it contains:
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",

which I installed with this commands:
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@latest


You seem to have -</div> after the self-closing minus icon component, I imagine that's a typo?

If you use the dev tools do you see the element with the class?

@DBS Oops that's a typo in my question, just edited it

I believe that you forgot to import the icons globally.
Try importing as below:
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { far } from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

export default App;

library.add(fas);  // Import fa-solid icons only
// library.add(fab, fas, far); // Import multiple fa styles icons

Otherwise, you need to import icon individually:
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faPlus, faMinus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

<button onClick={handleOpening} className="expandButton">
  {!isOpen ? (
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} />
  ) : (
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMinus} />
  )}
</button>

Demo @ StackBlitz
Reference: How to set up Font Awesome in React

Did you include these lines, it's required as per the documentation if you want to provide the value of icon= as string:
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { all } from '@awesome.me/kit-KIT_CODE/icons'

library.add(...all)

